# API for controlling the OWI-535 robot arm

Tags: c#, .net, python, robotics

For fun I've been fiddling with the OWI-535 robot arm, and I came across [this](http://notbrainsurgery.livejournal.com/38622.html) blog post about controlling the arm in Linux(or OSX). Has anyone done an API for it in .Net? Once again, a case of trying to not reinvent the wheel...

I did find [this](http://python-poly.blogspot.com/2011/01/in-beginning.html) about controlling it in Python, but I wanted to check if anyone had done a .Net version before I began chasing down the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) to control the arm.  It's not specifically for this purpose, but it gives you the tools to do it.

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/libusbdotnet/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=75) is an example program someone wrote using libusbdotnet.

Comment: Thanks! See, this is why I ask these questions and love StackOverflow!